# Data of redux store getting empty on reload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, reload

I am new to react and redux.
I have 3 screens in my react js application.
On First Screen, user input the **id** and that id get stored in redux store.
On submit of first screen button API is called which take **id** as a parameter and bring the data. I Store that data in redux store.
On Second Screen, I show that data after fetching it from store.
Problem arises when I reload the page, the data of redux store get initilized to initial state i.e. empty.

I want when I reload the page, request should again go to server and fetch the data.

NOTE - I dont have access to **id** on second screen after reload so I cant call API again inside useEffect Hook.
Secondly I dont want to store data in any storage.

Kindly assist.
Thank You

Comment: If you can't requery the API, and you can't persist it using some sort of browser storage, then I'm not sure you have any options left. Is there a reason why you don't want to use any storage? Could you put the `id` in a query param or something?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to persist state using redux. I recommend you go for redux persist. It's what I use.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33367708)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, redux or any react state is not maintained throughout a browser refresh without some sort of persistence to either a DB, or browser storage like localStorage or indexedDB.

IF you do decide to persist the redux store to maintain state through browser refreshes... I hear redux-persist is great for it. https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist. It will use local-storage or session storage depending on how it's configured.